# Tag a subset of data with Indicator in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have some data that looks like this

```
Table 1:
MemberID  BinaryIndicator PrescriptionMonth
   01           1               4
   01           2               8
   02           2               6
   02           1               6
   03           1               9
   04           1               10 
   05           2               5
```

There are two queries I would like to make.  In the first one, I want to change the `BinaryIndicator` of any `MemberID` that appear more than once to 1. In the second query, I want change the indicator to an ID's highest `PrescriptionMonth`field value.  If it's a tie, the `BinaryIndicator` would change to 1.  For example, Member with ID of 01 will have all its `BinaryIndicator` changed to 2.  ID 02 would have `BinaryIndicator` changed to 1.

I tried to get a subset of the table that contains records that appear more than once and have different `BinaryIndicator`, call it `Table2` .  Then I made the following query:

```
SELECT Table1.MemberID, Table1.BinaryIndicator,  IIf(Table1.MemberID=Table2.MemberID,"1",Table1.MemberID) AS IndicatorRevised
FROM Table1,Table2
GROUP BY Table1.MemberID,IndicatorRevised
```

Which doesn't work.  I also have no idea how to write the second query.

Any thoughts, suggestion would be appreciated.  I had very limited experience
in Access/SQL and I don't even know a good source to learn about these =/.  Any pointers for where to learn/practice would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the first one try grouping by member and counting it. For the second I think you'd need two queries - one with a grouping and on with a MAX(Month) - then JOIN them by MemberID and Month/mMaxMonth...

Comment: Not sure about the second query. Do you want to get a value of 1 in the BinaryIndicator on the row that has the highest PrescriptionMonth value?

Comment: @DavidBachmannJeppesen  Yeah that's what I meant, I have clarified it in the question.

Comment: You say you _"want to change the BinaryIndicator of any `MemberID` that appear more than once to 1"_ but your sample data has rows where the `MemberID` only appears once but the `BinaryIndicator` field _is already_ set to 1. In effect all rows will have the `BinaryIndicator` field set to 1. Please clarify why you need to set all the values to 1. Why not just execute the query `UPDATE Table1 SET BinaryIndicator=1`?

Comment: That was a bad example. In actual data some values of `BinaryIndicator` are 2. Essentially this rule would only apply to `MemberID` that appears more than once and have two different `BinaryIndicator` values. I have edited my sample data to provide a better example. @Tony

Comment: @CloudyConjuration - So you only want to change rows where _"`MemberID` appears more than once and has two different `BinaryIndicator` values"_. Could a situation occur where a `MemberID` appears more than once with the **same** `BinaryIndicator`value?

Comment: Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9f075/7) to get you started on selecting rows where the `MemberID` appears more than once. You will need to turn it in to an `UPDATE` query but that shouldn't be hard. I need to go to bed.....

Comment: @Tony Yes, and `Table2` was meant to be a subset of `Table1` that contains memberID that appear more than once AND different `BinaryIndicator`.  I have figured out how to do that part.  Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity!  Good night sir ;].

Answer (score 0):

The first query:

```
SELECT t.MemberId,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.MemberId) > 1 THEN 1
           ELSE t.BinaryIndicator END BinaryIndicator,
       t.PrescriptionMonth
FROM table1 t;
```

I'm not sure what you want in the second query. Will ask in a comment...

Comment: MS Access does not have the `PARTITION BY` syntax. Your query will not work for this question.

Comment: I want to change the indicator to an ID's highest PrescriptionMonthfield value. If it's a tie, the BinaryIndicator would change to 1. For example, Member with ID of 01 will have all its BinaryIndicator changed to 2. ID 02 would have BinaryIndicator changed to 1. I have clarified this in the question

Answer (score 0):

For the first one

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.BinaryIndicator = 1
WHERE Table1.MemberID IN (SELECT Table1.MemberID 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.MemberID
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
AND Table1.BinaryIndicator != 1
```